# Memory Management issues with LIExposeController in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am using "LIExposeController" to create new UIViewControllers. This brings up some memory warnings that I am not able to fix.

```
- (UIViewController *)newViewControllerForExposeController:(LIExposeController *)exposeController {
    UIViewController *viewcontroller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    return viewcontroller; // warning here saying object with a + 0 retain count returned to caller where a + 1 (owning) retain count is expected
}


- (void)shouldAddViewControllerForExposeController:(LIExposeController *)exposeController {
    [exposeController addNewViewController:[self newViewControllerForExposeController:exposeController]
                                  animated:YES];
} // warning here saying potential leak of an object



LIExposeController *exposeController = [[[LIExposeController alloc] init] autorelease];


    exposeController.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [self newViewControllerForExposeController:exposeController],
                                        nil]; // warning here saying potential leak of an object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method starting with `new` is expected to produce an object with retain count +1 and not an autoreleased/retain count +0 object. ARC and the Static Analyzer both follow these conventions as rules, and you should fix your code to meet them or rename your method to not clash with the conventions.